# jvector Map refresh or redraw map upon changing scale ,transx , or transY

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I tried setting the scale value of map after getting it as object , when  i zoom out the scale is set to the value i assigned , so I am sure it kinda works , the problem is i have to zoom out using scroll to refresh the map , so the question is : is there a method to refresh or redraw the map programmatically ?

here is a link for the plugin just in case someone is curious :
[jvectormaps](http://www.jvectormap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is searching for answer to same question:

this method will refresh your map `applyTransform()`

more methods can be found in the source code :

http://pastebin.com/s5GwcEMy

starting from line 226.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still interested into this topic.
You may try the function `updateSize` mentioned in the documentation of jvectormap
(tested @2.0.3, ref: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/)

and this is the result
[image: tryout]

BR,

Louis

https://louiscklaw.github.io